# create cassandra db user/role using python

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to create user in `cassandra using python driver`.
defined variable password

```
password=abcde
rows = session.execute("create user test_user with 'password')
```

> Syntax error in CQL query] message="line  password expecting K_PASSWORD

```
password=abcde
rows = session.execute("create user test_user with 'password')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `PASSWORD` reserved word in your syntax.  Also, `CREATE USER` is only used with versions of Cassandra prior to 3.x.  It's `CREATE ROLE` if you're on a version after that.

*Versions below 3.x*

```
CREATE USER test_user WITH PASSWORD 'abcde';
```

*3.x+*

```
CREATE ROLE test_user WITH PASSWORD='abcde';
```

Note that the newer versions require the password and `PASSWORD` to be separated by an equals ('=') symbol.

So in your Python script, it'd look something like this:

```
rows = session.execute("create role test_user with password='" + password1 + "' and login=true")
```

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you running? @cad

Comment: Cassandra 3.11.1

Comment: @cad Ok, then as per my examples, make sure to use an equal sign and the word “role” instead of “user.”  Also try putting the password text in quotes.

Comment: role with the syntax you mentioned above works but wouldn't be able to login as login=true is not mentioned. and tried login=true it errors out with invalid synatx. `CREATE ROLE test_user with password='" + password1 + "'" AND LOGIN = true`

Comment: @cad edit made.  Sorry, I assumed that the password was the hard part and that you could figure out the rest.  You have to treat ` and login=true` as a substring and concatenate on to the original string.

Comment: Thank you aaronit works. not sure why it doesn't work for user instead of role. though it manually works.